# Compare same tables in 2 different databases and 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 servers, one named DB2 (cloud), and one named OUS (on prem).

I have 2 databases, one named version1 (cloud), and one named version2 (on prem).

A person is adding a column in xyz entity on the version1 (cloud) database, and this new column in xyz entity must be added to version2 (on prem) database.

I am facing the issue of schema mismatch due to unmatched column, and 
I need a SQL query to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Alter table add column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.version2 ADD xyz VARCHAR(20) NULL;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/add-columns-to-a-table-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017